# How to get the number of days not the time.delta

Tags: python

I'm using the following command to get the number of days between two dates and add it as a new column to a DF.

```
dates_by_product['p2-p3'] = dates_by_product[3] - dates_by_product[2]
```

the problem is that its givng me the following: 309 days 06:30:29

and I need it to be just a number: 309

any ideas on how to make it just a number?

Comment: Do you see a slot on [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) which would give you the number of `days`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of `dates_by_product` are Date types from `datetime`, then if you subtract them you can call `days()` on them like so:

```
from datetime import date
d = date(2022, 8, 30) - date(2000, 1, 1)

print(d.days)
# 8277
```